# Finite groups principal bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

I am studying principal bundles from the point of view of algebraic geometry and I have come up with the following question. For the sake of clarity, a principal $G$-bundle over a scheme $X$ is just a faithfully flat scheme $P\rightarrow X$ equipped with a $G$-action which is free and transitive, and such that there exists an étale covering of $X$ such that the pullback of $P$ to each one of the open sets of the covering is isomorphic to the trivial $G$-bundle. Since finite groups are the most manageable groups to start with, is there any classification of principal bundles with a finite structural group? Are those principal bundles Zariski locally trivial?

Comment: This is essentially just the theory of the etale fundamental group. No they are not Zariski locally trivial in general, since finite etale covers are not Zariski locally trivial in general.

Comment: Can you provide some references?

Comment: Well you can read about this on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group. The principal $G$-bundles correspond to Galois finite etale covers.

Comment: As for counter-examples, pretty much any example you can write down will suffice. For example the map $\mathbb{G}_m \to \mathbb{G}_m, x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: I should add that in algebraic geometry one usually uses the terminology "$G$-torsor"; the phrase "principal $G$-bundle" is a bit of a mouthful and also gives misleading intuition, as I think your question demonstrates.

Comment: @SamanthaSmith - You should also post a question on the MSE site - on this site "moderators" tend to delete answers that may be of interest to the asker. In fact I posted an answer that was deleted by abx and Kohl - post a question on MSE and Ill post the answer there. I gave some references that may be of interest.